# Memcache Delete Also Deletes Database?

Tags: memcached

I'm working on client-server software that uses memcached.

If I want to delete content from my database that is held within memcached, which of the following is usually required to achieve this objective?

```
A - delete from database AND delete from memcached
B - delete from memcached (which will automatically delete from the database)
```

Thanks

Comment: `C - delete from database and invalidate memcached`.

Comment: deleting from the db upon deletion from memcache would seem counter productive - you'd have to differentiate between "delete because the cached object really is gone" v.s. "deleting from cache to make room for other stuff".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A is what you would want.

Memcache and your Database are completely separate and it is up to you to make them both reflect one another.

For example, if you insert into your DB you must also insert into memcache.  If you delete from your DB you must also delete from memcache.

In most of today's frameworks this is abstracted out.  However, if you are doing it manually then you must do both for consistent data.

Edit: by delete I mean invalidate